# searching column for matching data and displaying data from matching row to different work sheet excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking to do price updates,  have excel sheet with current prices and also have an excel sheet downloaded from our database. looking for a formula that will search for matching partnumber in a column and if it matches have it enter the new price in a column from the new list into the database excel sheet. the part number my be on the database more than once need it to add the new price every time that partnumber appears.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP formula sounds like it will be right for this one. Can you supply some sample data? It's a bit hard from your description.

But, without that, it would work something like this

```
=VLOOKUP(<part number cell>,<pricing data>,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: will that work if i am using 2 different worksheets?